# docker executable file not found in $PATH" react image

Tags: reactjs, docker, path, dockerfile

I am trying to run a freshly create react app made with create-react-app in docker. I have a Docker file which succesfully allows me to build the image, but when I try to run it I get:

```
PS C:\Users\Bertinator\desktop\gamelist\client> docker run client4 .
container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \".\": 
executable file not found in $PATH"
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from 
daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container
process caused "exec: \".\": executable file not found in $PATH".
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
PS C:\Users\Bertinator\desktop\gamelist\client>
```

This is my Docker file, which is place in the root folder of my create-react-app project:

```
FROM node:7.8.0
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn

COPY . .

RUN npm run build --production

RUN npm install -g serve

CMD serve -s build

EXPOSE 5000
```

Comment: What is client4? Could you provide more information about what container you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running from a Linux docker image on a Windows machine? That does not work.

Ref http://training.play-with-docker.com/beginner-linux/

> (...) Linux containers require the Docker host to be running a Linux kernel. For example, Linux containers cannot run directly on Windows Docker hosts. The same is true of Windows containers - they need to run on a Docker host with a Windows kernel.

When you say `docker run client4 .` you are asking docker to run that container and execute the `.` (dot) command which does not make sense. That is why you are getting the first error.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I am running it on Windows. Can't believe I was so stupid.